# jQuery selector for label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a magic jQuery selector that can select labels of input fields?

like `$('#myinput').getLabel()` or something?

or do I really have to use `$('label[for="myinput"]')` ?

Comment: What's wrong with `$('label[for="myinput"]')`?

Comment: BTW, do you know what *Jizz* means?

Comment: @adam: the immediately recognisable characteristics of a bird?

Comment: (Sometimes extended to refer to animals and plants)

Comment: Not in the UK, and not on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jizz)

Comment: Obviously UK and the Urban Dictionary are wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always define it as a jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.getLabel = function () {
    var name = this.attr('name');
    if (!name) {
        // No id, so we can't find the label
        return $();
    }

    return $('label[for="' + name+ '"]');
};
```

(You might also want to handle possible `"`s in the id somehow)

Comment: You should take the `name` attribute and not the `id`. The `for` attribute of a label refers to the `name` of the input afaik. But +1, I was going to write something similar.

Comment: +1, although having a `"` in an ID is not valid and would likely cause HTML render issues too.

Comment: @Felix - I was commenting on the fact that configurator (the author of the answer) had written that it's worth checking for `"` in the ID before using it in the selector

Comment: @adam: Oh.... I might have missed the last sentence... sry. Should go to sleep I guess ;)

Comment: @adam: I've seen some weird ids work properly. Although I wouldn't put a `"` in an id myself, I wouldn't put it past some other people to define elements as `<a id='my "id" has quotes in it'>`